# Python-Counting element frequency in a 2D list

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a way to count element frequencies in a 2D python list.
For 1D lists, we can use

```
list.count(word)
```

but what if I have  a list:

```
a = [ ['hello', 'friends', 'its', 'mrpycharm'], 
      ['mrpycharm', 'it', 'is'], 
      ['its', 'mrpycharm'] ]
```

can i find the frequency for each word in this 2D list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want,

```
>>> collections.Counter([x for sublist in a for x in sublist])
Counter({'mrpycharm': 3, 'its': 2, 'friends': 1, 'is': 1, 'it': 1, 'hello': 1})
```

Or,

```
>>> c = collections.Counter()
>>> for sublist in a:
...     c.update(sublist)
...
>>> c
Counter({'mrpycharm': 3, 'its': 2, 'friends': 1, 'is': 1, 'it': 1, 'hello': 1})
```

Comment: Do you know if using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension would result in a speedup?  `Counter(x for sublist in a for x in sublist)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for sublist in a:
    for word in sublist:
        d[word] += 1
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why is it a wrong collection?

Comment: Look at sberry's answer

Comment: but this seems to work fine too

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: But that doesn't makes it the wrong collection.

Comment: It works fine. A normal `dict` would also work fine too. But if you are already going to import from collections, why not use the collection *made for counting elements*?

Comment: Not the wrong collection, just a different choice.  Prior to its introduction in 2.7 this is exactly how I would have done it.  For what it's worth, for this size data on my machine (and CPython2.7) this solution is more than 50% faster than using Counter.

Answer (score 1):

You already know about `list.count()`. Simply get the count of word in each `sublist` and `sum` them. For example:

```
>>> my_word = 'its'
>>> sum(sublist.count(my_word) for sublist in a)
2
```

In case you want the frequency of every word present in your `list`, there are many good answers available here for that. Alternatively, in case you want to do it without any `import` (using normal `dict`), you may do:

```
my_dict = {}
for sublist in a:
    for item in sublist:
        if item not in my_dict:
            my_dict[item] = 0
        my_dict[item] += 1

# Value of my_dict:
{'friends': 1, 'is': 1, 'it': 1, 'its': 2, 'mrpycharm': 3, 'hello': 1}
```