# Mode of a column in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
distances = [[female, 1],
[female, 2],  
[male, 3],
[male, 4],
[female, 5]]
```

How can I get the mode(max occurrence among the elements) of the first column upto first k lists.
like, if k = 3, it should return *'female'* as female occurs twice while male occurs once

Comment: what do you mean by *mode of the first column*? Do you mean the max count for first `k` rows? your output for `k=3` is `female` because it appears twice while `male` only once? be more specific

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes the element with the highest frequency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-Counting element frequency in a 2D list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140067/python-counting-element-frequency-in-a-2d-list)

Comment: @Tomerikoo The link doesn't answer the question completely, I am not looking for all the frequency counts just the mode of a specific column. Also the answers there are for all the elements not just a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the builtin statistics module for its mode function, and `operator.itemgetter` will allow easy access to just the first element in each list.

```
from statistics import mode
from operator import itemgetter

distances = [['female', 1], ['female', 2], ['male', 3], ['male', 4], ['female', 5]]
k = 3

print(mode(map(itemgetter(0), distances[:k])))
#'female'
```

You can also use `collections.Counter` to get counts of each sex.

```
Counter(map(itemgetter(0), distances[:k])))
#Counter({'female': 3, 'male': 2})
```

And you can use `max` on that too and come up with the same result:

```
sexes = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), distances[:k]))
print(max(sexes, key=sexes.get))
#'female'
```

Comment: This is working , but how do I add the range , I mean upto first k rows/lists ?

Comment: You left out `k`, but it's easy to add: `k = 3; print(... distances[:k])))`

Comment: Added `k` into my answer, also added counter as another solution as it can be useful for other situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
distances = [['female', 1],
['female', 2],  
['male', 3],
['male', 4],
['female', 5]]

def get_mode(k_max):
    l = [d[0] for d in distances[:k_max]] # make list of elements up to given k_max
    return max(set(l), key=l.count) # return most frequent element

get_mode(3)
'female'
```

This assumes that the list of lists is ordered, as in your example.

Comment: Simpler: `l = [d[0] for d in distances[:k_max]]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```py
import statistics as stats

female = 'f'
male = 'm'

distances = [[female, 1],
[female, 2],  
[male, 3],
[male, 4],
[female, 5]] 
distmode = []
k = 0
for i in distances:
    distmode.append(i[0]) #take first entry in each list
    k += 1
    if k >= 3: #break at k=3
        break
print(stats.mode(distmode))
```

Comment: Simpler: `k = 3; distmode = [d[0] for d in distances[:k]]`